# 'company calendar' that propagates to all employees' personal calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, calendar

I am wondering if there is a way to set this up in outlook, either native or through addons, and if not, what would be an alternative scheduling software that would make this possible.

I would like to have a 'master calendar' for the company whose events propagate to the local calendars on each user's device.  Right now we have a master calendar on Exchange and individual calendars (I am not sure if they are set up clientside or serverside to be honest.  if it matters I can find out).  my boss syncs his calendar to a blackberry, but apparently he can only sync with one calendar, and several other employees have mentioned similar concerns.

is there a way that I can have a master calendar on which all events will automatically propagate to all users with access to that calendar?  if not in outlook, is there another application with this functionality?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs:

Microsoft will let you share Hotmail calendars:
http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/familysync.aspx#fbid=HcG77zOisEG

I however recommend Google Calendar, which will let you share calendars as well. It has helpful features such as "find open times for meetings", alert via email/SMS, syncs great with all Android phones, and so on. I find it more suited for sharing with people and creating events that are for specific groups. 
https://www.google.com/calendar/

Comment: Well there are rly only two (theoretically) calendars at play, there is the communal calendar, which includes meetings etc that everyone must attend, which is handled by the ofc mgr but is shared with and thus viewable and editable by everyone, and the individual calendars, which contain individual appointments and are handled by the individuals in question.  I'd like rather than everybody having to reference two calendars, which some phones can't do, that they can just have the master/communal calendar propagate to others.

Comment: "Google calendar" lets you have as any number or calendars as you wish, and you pick and choose which ones to show. When two are shown at a time, they are merged into one calendar (visually) but are color coded.
As for blackberry, I'm sorry but I haven't used that in years but there may be a way to use Google if you so desire.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if Google calendar might be able to sync to Exchange, or will I have to roll the whole office over?  It'd be ideal if I could set up an intermediary Google calendar for each employee who is having issues with their phone, but not have to hold a lot of hands while everybody gets used to a totally new calendar.

Comment: You can share the communal, which anyone can update in realtime, and the private ones will stay private.

Comment: Right... but is it possible, for example, to share an Outlook calendar with a Google user?  I don't know if they use compatible protocols, I know Outlook/Exchange CAN share with other services, but I don't know about Google.

Comment: This page says you can, although I've never tried it. http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33322  -- 
Then this page says "active sync" is no longer supported as of January. http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2413283,00.asp

That last page may be irrelevant? I can't tell.

Comment: Yeah, I have done about 20 hours of research in the last week, apparently having more than one calendar isn't a necessary feature for what is supposed to be the 'enterprise professional's phone'.  Seems stupid, but they're the ones losing market share, I'm sure they know what they're doing.